# Can we change the owner of a Solana account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, account

I have a solana account created by a solana program deployed on the devnet. Is it possible to change the owner of the account? If yes then can you please tell how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely update the owner of an account, but it must be done by the currently owning program, using the `assign` function on `AccountInfo`. Here's a simple example of reassigning to the system program:

```
account_info.assign(&system_program::id());
```

This was taken from the token program, which reassigns to the system program when an account is closed: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/3db25f26867b0ff0386b2683a28d71b194eba388/token/program/src/processor.rs#L1025

For this to work, however, the account must be all zeroes. Otherwise, it would be possible to craft an account that looks like it has 1 billion USDC, and then reassign the account to the token program!