# My wallet can't send sol to others and can't mint nft

Tags: nft, account, error

I met a problem my sol address can't send out sol to another wallet but can send it into it, and my address can't mint nft. Really don't know what's with it. Really strange. My address is
BvCYmvJ2m4mPAtkFjQUPWSYzqoxevMY9vG729kAuqbP9

Below is the capture. Thx a lot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might happen if your account is no longer a `SystemAccount`(i.e an account owned by the System Program). Only system accounts are allowed to be fee-payers for a transaction. You can find the check that throws the error above [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/537c3d8e2ce3e50c1d98a564f7eb3dde289fc3dd/svm/src/account_loader.rs#L414).

Check the recent transactions leading up to the weird behaviour. The most likely explanation is that an instruction modified your account by initializing it as an account owned by a different(maybe random) program.

This might happen for instance when you make a mistake in constructing any instruction that initializes a program-account, and pass your provider wallet in place of the account that should have been initialized. Now your account would no longer be owned by the system-program, and instead will be owned by the new program.

A few answers describing how to rectify this already exist, namely [(1)](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/can-we-change-the-owner-of-a-solana-account) and [(2)](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/how-to-change-owner-of-owned-account).

Comment: It seems my wallet is be hacked and can we provide some solutions about this attack?